# MYSQL one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I started transforming whole database to a normalised database. But there is one thing which I dont understand about relationships:

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Users
-userID (INT-PK)
-userName (varchar)
_favColor (int)
```

And:

```
Colors
-colorID (INT-PK)
-colorName (varchar)
```

Now obviously I have to create a relationship, the question is:
Should I make relationship between Colors Table and Users Table, or between Users Table and Colors Table?

What I've noticed is that when creating a relationship, the relationship does not appear in both tables, it appears in just one of them, and this makes me confused.

Comment: I'd make favColor a FK to the Colours table. Many people could have the same favourite colour. By making it a foreign key you can make sure that the colour exists in the colours table.

Comment: users table will contain the color_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example I would recommend a 1:M relationship, going from colours to users.

This is because the users table requires information from the colours table, the reason why you'd have a 1:M relationship is because different users may have the same favourite colour.

Comment: So If I create a relationship between Colors to Users, I wouldnt be able to set same color for different users?

Comment: Users._favColor should be a Foreign Key to the colours table.

You will be able to set whatever colour for any users.